# How to create a Sequence number based on Sales Agent name and sale date in excel using formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sequence, countif

I am looking for a formula which can write the sequence no based on the criteria of Salesperson name and Sale order Date.  below is the sample table. Please check if anyone can help me.

[image]

I tried using countif

```
=COUNTIFS(C$2:C2,"<="&C2,A$2:A2,A2)
```

but not getting the expected results as given in the image

Comment: Please show what you mean by `not getting the expected results`  That formula at first glance should give you what you want.

Comment: You can refer the table given, example Agent1 and his Lowest date should have the value as 1, and next highest date for agent1 should be 2.. like that it should sequence

Comment: I can see what it should be, I want to know what your error is.  The formula works for me if I put the dates in column C and the agent id in column A.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I found a way to by just changing the range.

Comment: Hi, getting duplicate sequence number in case of Agent and date are similar. Shared the Screen shot.

Comment: @Sridharan If your comment is to be addressed to a particular user, use the `@` with the user name as I did in this comment. If you want to complain about a particular user's answer, add a comment below the answer.

Comment: Don't think solution given by @VBasic2008 Sir will return duplicate sequence. It returns unique. Also there is no screenshot shared as mentioned in the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula gives this result

`=MATCH(B2,SORT(TOCOL(IF(A$2:A$8=A2,B$2:B$8,1/0),3),1,1),0)`

[image]

Comment: Thank you,Black cat!, I learned a new method from you.

Answer (score 1):

### Running Count - Ascending

```
=LET(data,A2:B10,
    st,HSTACK(SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)),data),
    so,TAKE(SORT(st,{2;3}),,2),
    d,DROP(so,,1),
    s,d=VSTACK("",DROP(d,-1)),
    sc,SCAN(0,s,LAMBDA(sr,r,IF(r,sr+1,1))),
    r,SORTBY(sc,TAKE(so,,1)),
    r)
```

[image]